# Deploy new translations on production in ASP MVC with westwind globalization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, westwind, westwind-globalization

I'm adding globalization using [westwind globalization](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.Globalization)  in my asp mvc app that is already running on production server (Git, TeamCity with continuous delivery).

What I want to achieve if flow as follow:

- globalize a new view (create necessary translations)
- send all changes to Git
- get translated view - without worry about manual import of new translations in Localization Panel.

The only solution that came to my mind is to use EF Migrations (app is using EF Code First):

- add Localizations table to Code First model and create migration
- globalize the new view and create (some how automtically) a new migration which inserts a new records to Localizations table.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something, but westwind globalization is storing the strings in the database. So is your idea to not directly translate in the live db, but locally first and then move it to live somehow?

Comment: @Remy -yep that was initial idea but I ended up with different solution. Just created a wrapper for DbRes.T method which creates a default translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with different solution:
I created a wrapper for DbRes.T method which creates initial translation.

Edit:
More details about solution.

I created a static class Translations with a few methods used in views.
After first call default values are added.
One of them looks sth like that:

```
public static string 
    Translate(string resourceSet, string key, string defaultEnglish)
    {
        var currentLang = GetValidCurrentCulture();

        var resourceValue = DbRes.TDefault(key, null, resourceSet, currentLang);
        if (resourceValue == null)
        {
            AddDefaultTranslations(resourceSet, key, defaultEnglish);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceValue))
        {
            return defaultEnglish;
        }

        return resourceValue;
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate that a little more? Might be interesting for other people too, as I've seen this issue a few times.